# ColdFusion > 2016. SerializeJSON preserve Order with duplicate items

Tags: json, coldfusion

I am using myStruct=createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init();
to create a JSON structure using SerializeJSON. I have followed following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071784/how-can-i-preserve-the-assign-order-in-a-structure-in-coldfusion-2016#new-answer).

But I came across following challenge:

I am given  a JSON structure in which there are 2 child items have same key. If you look below, "item" key is the same for both children under "items". And order need to be preserved.

```
   {
   "Items" : {
        "item": {
          "itemId": "1",
          "name": "item1 descr",
        },
        "item": {
          "itemId": "222",
          "name": "item2 descr",
        }
      }
 }
```

How to create a structure so that  SerializeJSON works and order is preserved as shown above. Thanks for your help!

Note: ColdFusion > 2016. So new ideas should work,

Comment: Structure key names must be unique. You can't have multiple instances of the same key name. If that's what you need, wrap the child items in an array `[]`, not a structure `{}`.

Comment: FWIW, CF 2016 supports ordered structures out of the box, but it sounds like you should be using an array instead.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like this

```
<cfscript>
   data =    {
   "Items" : [ {
          "itemId": "1",
          "name": "item1 descr"
        },
        {
          "itemId": "222",
          "name": "item2 descr"
        }
     ]
   }

   writedump(data)

   </cfscript>
```

Note that the items in the array do not get the individual name `item`

See: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=37b87d2a-5e11-4c08-bdba-c984f457f38c/5212ecb1-c3d3-4527-8d53-7d98cea655cf/b222f5f7-b3fb-4e01-889a-a99b3f208ccb.cfm